# How do I verify if a conversion from docx to pdf is correct?

Tags: pdf, conversion, docx, verification

I can't check thousands of PDF files to see if the source DOCX is identical.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: How are you defining "correct"? Do you want a 100% identical **graphical** representation? Or do you need a textual comparison? How are the documents exported to pdf? What options are used? What have you tried so far?

Comment: 100% correctness is not possible because there are visual differences between two PDF files created with an Adobe printer and an Adobe DC conversion. I tried to print both files, docx and pdf, as an image and then compare these images, there were of course differences which were minimal, I am not looking for small pixel differences. I need more a check if the conversion was free of errors like lost images, letters or heavily changed formatting etc.. So bigger differences. A pdf validation says nothing about the content of the file(verapdf).